# How to create a link to a content on a webpage created with aspx

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to create a direct link to an entry in a webpage which is created using aspx

for example, the page I'm interested in creating a direct link to is:

https://cad.chp.ca.gov/Traffic.aspx

After I select the "Communication Centers" on the top left I get a list of incidents and I can click on the "Detail" to see additional info.
While holding the mouse over the "Detail" link I get a javascript link like this:

```
     javascript:__doPostBack('gvIncidents','Select$4')
```

How do I go directly to the detail section of a certain incident?

Comment: A link by itself isn't going to invoke any JavaScript.  A link can only contain query string elements.  The page itself is going to have to respond to those elements in some way.  If there's a way to direct link to that functionality, you may need to ask the maintainer(s) of that site what it is.

Comment: You could send someone a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) or [userscript](https://github.com/OpenUserJs/OpenUserJS.org/wiki/Userscript-beginners-HOWTO) that would browse to the page and then invoke the javascript, however, these approaches are inherently insecure (when using someone else's scripts) and are too advanced for use by the general public

Comment: I'm not sure what you want will be possible using that page. There is no direct URL to any specific incident details.